# Inserting into my table using a custom method is not working, but if I put in the create connection method it works fine

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Inserting into my table using a custom method is not working, but if I put in the create connection method it works fine.

This is the method I wrote to insert into the table, this method is in a different file, the caller method is also in a different file.
When the method is called, it does nothing but stops the program execution with no errors.

```
void insertIntoPatientTable(@NotNull Connection conn){
   System.out.println("inside the insert");
   final String insertStatement =
           "INSERT INTO Patients(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, " +
           "PHONE_NUMBER, NEXT_OF_KIN_NAME, NEXT_OF_KIN_PHONE_NUMBER)" +
           "VALUES( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)" ;
   try{
       System.out.println("inside try block");
       System.out.println(conn.isClosed());
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
       preparedStatement.setString(1, "John");
       preparedStatement.setString(2, "Doe");
       preparedStatement.setInt(4, 24);
       preparedStatement.setString(3, "will");
       preparedStatement.setInt(5, 34);
       preparedStatement.setInt(6, 14);
       preparedStatement.execute();
       System.out.println("executed");
   }catch (SQLException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This is the method that calls it. Each time I call the method, it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
void createConnection() {
    setPASSWORD(" ");
    try{
        setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(getUrlString().concat(getTIMEZONE()), getUSER(), getPASSWORD()));
        Connection dbConnection = getConn();
        CRUD_Statements patientModel = new CRUD_Statements();

        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        String userStatement = patientModel.createPatientTable();
        patientModel.insertIntoPatientTable(dbConnection);
        statement.execute(userStatement);

        List<PatientModel> patient = new ArrayList<>();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're catching an exception and ignoring (`ex.getMessage()` only retrieves the message, it doesn't log or print anything). Use `ex.printStacktrace()` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have two problems here:

1. You invoke `patientModel.insertIntoPatientTable` before creating the table with `statement.execute(userStatement)`. If the table really doesn't exist before you try to insert into it, `insertIntoPatientTable` is going to throw an Exception, but you're catching the Exception and not displaying it. Try replaceing  `ex.getMessage()` with `ex.printStacktrace()`
2. If `insertIntoPatientTable`, it's going to close the connection, but then you try to re-use the connection in `createConnection` after `insertIntoPatientTable` returns.

So, make sure that you log all of your exceptions, and don't close your connection until you're really done with it.

You'll probably also have a problem with creating the table if you run this a second time, as the table will already exist.

Finally, if the table doesn't exist, you'll need to create before you try to access it, not after.

Comment: there is no error message coming in from the method. i have printed the 'stackTrace' but then it just exits the program without errors. i also refactored the code and put the insert statement in the calling method 'createConnection()' and it works there but i have to use this method in several other places during program execution.

Answer (score 0):

it has been fixed. the problem was with the get message, immediately i printed the stackTrace i found out it was throwing errors the getMessage() wasn't picking. Apparently it was a problem with my datatype in the table.